# Intellij: Any way to go to next error anywhere in the project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

Is there any way to go to next error that is anywhere in the project within IntelliJ? Going to `Next Highlighted Error` only goes to errors within the opened file rather than anywhere in the project.

Comment: IDE does not know about every error in the project in most cases. Analysis is run when you open a file, otherwise performance would suffer. There is support for Project wide error analysis, but it's limited to some languages only. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-and-project-analysis.html#project-wide-analysis. At the moment, it works only for Java.

Comment: in Rider it is, I think Alt-Shift-PageDown (and -PageUp for previous). Not sure about IntelliJ.